# fixing bit width mismatch

Tags: verilog, lint

I've run this code to the lint checker (spyglass):

```
     1 module test(
     2         output  [7:0] O_O,
     3         input   [7:0] I_1,
     4         input   [7:0] I_2
     5 );
     6
     7         wire    [14:0] result;
     8
     9         assign result = (I_1 + I_2) << 5;
    10         assign O_O = result[7:0];
    11 endmodule
```

I get this warning message:

```
    Bit-width mismatch in signal assignment (LHS: 'O_O' width 8 should match RHS: '((I_1 + I_2) << 5)' width 14). [Hierarchy:test]
```

To avoid this warning, I changed my code like this:

```
     1 module test(
     2         output  [7:0] O_O,
     3         input   [7:0] I_1,
     4         input   [7:0] I_2
     5 );
     6         wire    [15:0] result;
     7
     8         assign result = (I_1 + I_2) << 5;
     9         assign O_O = result[7:0];
    10 endmodule
```

Then got this warning message

```
    Port 'O_O[4:0]' is 'tied-low'
```

Any recommendations to fix those warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
 1 module test(
 2         output  [7:0] O_O,
 3         input   [7:0] I_1,
 4         input   [7:0] I_2
 5 );
 6
 7         wire    [14:0] result = (I_1 + I_2) << 5;
 8
 9         assign O_O = result[7:0];
10 endmodule
```

Comment: I tried it but still I get the warning message: 'Port 'O_O[4:0]' is 'tied-low'

Comment: You may need to contact the makers of [SpyGlass](http://www.atrenta.com/solutions/spyglass-family.htm) for technical support.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a way to tell your lint checker that you intend those bits to be always zeros.  You'll have to read the docs to find out how though - maybe a special comment you can add int he source, or a separate config file to say "expect this warning on this line of code"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a waiver file to waive all such warnings in spyglass.

Answer (score 0):

In warning window there is option for shifting this warning to waiver file, i,e

```
.awl
.swl
```

which will show intentionally added stuff and need to ignored, doesn't reflected in warning window any more.